# Read a TSV file from a remote server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this function  which returns the path to the file I need to read

```
def specie_to_file(specie):
    switcher = {
    'human': 'sftp://eliran@SERVER/PATH/TO/FILE1',
    'mouse': 'sftp://eliran@SERVER/PATH/TO/FILE2'
    }
    return switcher.get(specie, None)
```

Later on, I am trying to open the file

```
database = pd.read_csv(db_file, sep='\t')
```

`db_file` holds one of the paths above.

When I execute the script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
  File "gene_converter.py", line 111, in converter
    database = pd.read_csv(open(db_file), sep='\t')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sftp://eliran@SERVER/PATH/TO/FILE1'
```

I have checked the files names and the paths they all exist and in the right location.

I have tried the following and got the same traceback:

```
database = pd.read_csv(Path(db_file), sep='\t')
```

```
database = pd.read_csv(open(db_file,'r'), sep='\t')
```

```
database = pd.read_csv(open(db_file,'r').read(), sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is on FTP server.

Use [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) in order to read it.

```
with sftp.open("sftp://eliran@SERVER/PATH/TO/FILE1") as f:
    pd.read_csv(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per docs:

"filepath_or_bufferstr, path object or file-like object
Any valid string path is acceptable. The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, gs, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. A local file could be: file://localhost/path/to/table.csv.

If you want to pass in a path object, pandas accepts any os.PathLike.

By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO."

SFTP does not show up in the list of supported URL schemes. Accordingly, you should build a StringIO object out of the URL and pass it to read_csv.

Install SFTP library. Download file, then read it.
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html

Comment: I have tried ```database = pd.read_csv(open(db_file, 'r').read(), sep='\t')``` and got the same traceback.
Tried also without the ```.read()``` and same result.
Is that what you meant or I got you wrong?